# In Genesis 29:18, what is the significance that Jacob offered to work for Laban, seven years for Rachel?

Tags: genesis, history, jacob, bride

Genesis 29:18 (NASB)

> Now Jacob loved Rachel, so he said, “I will serve you seven years for your younger daughter Rachel.”

And why not *fewer* years?

Comment: Laban was somewhat avarice and bargained.  Only the conclusion of the bargaining is recorded.  See https://biblehub.com/commentaries/genesis/29-18.htm

Comment: Dottard Correct Laban was greedy, he bartered for both of his daughters., Although he played the part of the benevolent uncle, he reduced his blood relationship with Jacob to a service contract. Since Jacob was in love with Rachel, he replied: "I am will serve you seven years for your younger daughter Rachel." What would seven years in wages amount to?

Comment: A LOT of money indeed

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be simply that the seven years totaled up to a reasonable value of Jacob's labor which he was willing to "pay" eventually for Rachel and ultimately for Leah. I'm not sure if the exact value may be calculated today so that we may know if the value he was placing on Rachel was more than or equal to the standard rate that was expected for a bride. Whatever the "value" was for those years of work, it was acceptable to Laban. Dickering over the value of a bride may have been an insult to the bride. The "seven" years may have been more reflective of how much Jacobs ability to work was worth.

Comment: Glen : It is a very good answer +1, Seven years wages and most likely a 12 hour day, the then wages amounted to 50 shekels of silver. Perhaps you can research and find todays values for a worker.

Comment: The median wage for a laborer is $14.47/hr. https://www.payscale.com/research/US/Job=Laborer/Hourly_Rate

Comment: Take that $14.47 *12hrs/day* seven days/week*52weeks*seven years = $442,434.72.  Sounds like a lot of money.  I would hope that Laban provided Jacob with essentials like food, clothing.

Comment: Glenn ::Yes, it is an awful lot of money, he was in love. But more so he could have refused. Laban was obliged to provide food and shelter. Jacob did not refuse for a very important reason. Why?